# weird ActiveRecord time zone behavior in Rails on multiple servers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, amazon-s3

Our application is hosted on AWS with 8 app servers (Unicorn) + 3 RDS (1 Master + two read replica) + 2 Redis (Master + slave) all are located in one region  All 8 app servers have BST time zone and also 2 redis, we have applied time zone as 'London' in application.rb,

The problem is on show page start date, end date displayed value is sometimes displayed as Start date **Friday 01-10-2015 - 18:30** and sometimes as **Friday 01-10-2015 - 19:30** the value reflect of refresh (ctrl + F5).

Has anyone faced a similar problem?

Ravi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fix this issue, by adding `around filter` in your `application_controller` to override the weird behaviour of `active_record` - timezone.

```
around_filter :use_time_zone

private

def use_time_zone(&block)
  Time.use_zone('London', &block)
end
```

So, whenever the default timezone changed to UTC, it will override and set as BST.